# How to know the OpenSSL version for WebApp hosted in Azure cloud

Tags: azure, security, openssl, azure-web-app-service

I know it is not related to coding but really need to know this. Already googled it but no concrete answer was found.

The client wants to know whether our application is vulnerable to the latest vulnerability which is found in OpenSSL.
CVE-2022-3786
CVE-2022-3602

Reference: https://snyk.io/blog/new-openssl-critical-vulnerability/

Answer (score 3):

You can find vulnerable machines with Defender for Cloud’s inventory tools:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
2. Navigate to **Microsoft Defender for Cloud** > **Inventory**
3. Use the built-in filters to find your at-risk machines:

   - Use the **Installed applications** filter to search for “contains openssl” or specific packages
   - Use the **Installed applications versions** filter to find the affected versions (3.0.0-3.0.6)
     Source: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-cloud/new-openssl-v3-vulnerability-prepare-with-microsoft-defender-for/ba-p/3666487

According to [Tenable](https://www.tenable.com/blog/cve-2022-3786-and-cve-2022-3602-openssl-patches-two-high-severity-vulnerabilities):

> OpenSSL version 3.0.7 has been released to address these vulnerabilities.

You won't say what kind of WebApp you have but updating OpenSSL in your WebApp will be enough.

UPDATE

You can get your OpenSSL Version with the command `openssl version`

You can find the app service console in your Azure portal

[image]

Comment: There is the App Service tag, so OP is probably using that :) Updating OS libraries isn't really something you can do on App Service as those servers are managed by Microsoft.

Comment: Yes right. I am using App Service.

Comment: Can you guys please guide me on how to check OpenSSL version? As I am a QA not Dev. So should I tell Dev to update the latest OpenSSL. The above link is mostly about the virtual machines but as I am using App Service. Will this be automatically taken care by microsoft?
@juunas

Comment: @rAJ your app service is Windows or Linux?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]

Comment: @rAJ I Update the answer with the command and the place where you can find the console

Comment: Mine is also showing a 1.1.1g version.
Is this OpenSSL thing more related to the server rather than the application level? 
As I am using azure cloud servers then we can not do anything to upgrade this. It will update by Microsoft itself. Right?

Answer (score 1):

MSFT announced Defender CSPM at Ignite, one of the features of DCSPM is Cloud Security Explorer and it has a built in template for this exact scenario.  The feature is in preview and can be used for free (for now)

[OpenSSL Detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnGTB.png)